# Learn Ruby on Rails (Object Oriented Knowledge already acquired)

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to learn Ruby on Rails. I have a strong knowledge of Java Programming Language.
Do I need to go over Ruby and then on to RoR?

Or just Moving on to RoR should be enough?

Comment: If you're asking a question about Rails, don't forget to tag it Rails.

Answer (score 1):

It would be beneficial to learn the Ruby language first - the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/) are a good starting point.

Once you're familiar with Ruby then you can move onto learning the Rails framework - there are loads of tutorials / screencasts around that will help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to study Ruby first. RoR, for all the hype, is just a framework on top of Ruby. Without a decent knowledge of Ruby all you can do with RoR is follow examples by rote, not going far beyond generated code, and having great difficulty understanding the RoR documentation.

Also, Java programmers in particular seem to really appreciate the Ruby language. Its concision is a joy after Java's verbosity. So while studying Ruby is something you have to do to go very far with RoR, it's also something you get to do. For me using Ruby has been the most fun I've had programming since playing with QuickBASIC 30 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (and I was kind of in the same situation as you are now), the most important thing is that you have to get familiar with webprogramming in general, and the MVC design pattern in particular.

When I started with Rails, I noticed the hardest part wasn't the Ruby language and its constructs, but it were the general concepts on how people currently build websites, which at the time, I wasn't aware of.

If you already know this stuff, and you're Java skills are strong, then I expect you won't encounter many problems when you dive in Rails right away.

By the way, this is an excellent starting point: [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can go straight to Rails. check out http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely do a bit of Ruby first but don't worry about going to in-depth. There are a few Rails tutorials out there that also cover Ruby while you're learning rails. Have a look here: [Top 11 Ruby on Rails Learning Tools](http://madproject.com/general/top-11-ruby-on-rails-learning-tools/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rails is a framework, Ruby is the language.  Since you are a Java programmer, think of Rails as something similar to Spring or Struts.  Asking if you should learn Ruby before Rails is about the same as asking if you could do stuff with the Spring framework without first learning Java.